# Share Specific directory in app's Documents with Files app

Tags: ios, objective-c, file

I created an iOS app with file manager that browses inside subfolder in Documents.
The folders in app's documents are:

- Settings
- Root
- Tmp
- trash

The app's file manager browses only inside "Root" folder. Other folders must be hidden to users and inaccessible.

I want to share the "Root" folder with Files App that comes with iOS, so I added the following keys in info.plist:

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
```

It worked, but all of the folders are exposed, I only want to expose "Root" folder.

Is it possible to share a specific folder in Files app ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a reason why `Settings`, `Tmp`, and `trash` need to be in the `Documents` folder at all, as opposed other folders (such as the application support directory)? See [Where You Should Put Your App’s Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW28). Also see [iOS Storage Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/204/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before using file system of iOS, Please check the usage of different directories of the iOS file system.

You can refer this link: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

As per above link, apple has clearly mentioned that:

For **Documents** Directory : It clearly says that `this directory should only contain files that you may wish to expose to the user.`

[image]

If you want something that should not be exposed to User, then dont use `Documents` directory, instead use `Library` directory for this.

For `Library` directory: `Use the Library subdirectories for any files you don’t want exposed to the user. Your app should not use these directories for user data files.`

[image]

Here, see the following screenshot from above link, which says about which directory to use when?

[image]

In short, keep your root directories content in Document directory and move all other directory with their content to Library directory OR Library/Application Support Directory. So, your intended purpose will get fulfilled.